# SQL: List of users that logged out 1 minute after they logged in

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
log_id | user_id | login_date | logout_date
```

I need to run a query to get the users that logged out up to 1 minute after they logged in.

So if a user logged in at 2:02:02, and then logged out at 2:02:34. I would want them in this list.

But, a user that logged in at 2:03:00 and then logged out at at 2:04:01 I would not want them in this list.

Any ideas how to write this query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from yourTable
where datediff(ss, login_date, logout_date) <= 60
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user_id FROM tbl WHERE logout_date <= DATEADD(mi, 1, login_date)
```

Of course, if your table holds one record for each login this will return you *logins* rathers than *users*. So the same user could appear multiple times if they have had a sub-one-minute login multiple times...

If you just want a list of user_ids which have at any point logged in for less than a minute then do...

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tbl WHERE logout_date <= DATEADD(mi, 1, login_date)
```